# Flask POST requests hang when application deployed on IIS 7.5

Tags: python, flask, iis

I used a small flask test application from Miguel Grinberg's [blog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) and tried to deploy it on IIS. It works run fine on my local system where `POST` requests are working.

But a problem occurs when I deploy it to IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter edition).

I used this [post](https://gist.github.com/solevangelist/5845664) to configure IIS.

Then when I perform a `POST` request to the server I don't get a response back.

**My code:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import abort
from flask import make_response,request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@app.route('/dsebws', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():    
    d=request.data
    tp= str(type(d))
    return jsonify({'task': tp}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=Tr
```

ue)

**Test result local using python `app.py`:**

```
C:\Users\xyz>curl -v -X POST -d "Test" http://localhost:5000/dsebws
* About to connect() to localhost port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /dsebws HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 4
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 4 out of 4 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 28
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
< Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 00:30:54 GMT
<
{
  "task": "<type 'str'>"
}* Closing connection #0
```

**Tested on IIS Server:**

```
PS C:\Users\tarik> curl -v -X POST -d "tarik" http://localhost:80/dsebws
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /dsebws HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 5
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 5 out of 5 bytes
```

And it hangs there. After some time (15 mins) I get a long HTML response says something about a timeout.

Comment: Please add the "something" to your post.

Comment: tried to send a json of content length 388 ... but still...same problem, no reply

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing a WSGI reference?

Try putting in the following modifications at the end of your code

```
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```